# How to implement "for each" loop in android

Tags: java, foreach

Please help me to change this for loop into for each loop

`for (int i: size) {` --- I have tried this, but it's not working as a foreach loop in android studio.

```
int size = RecordManager.getInstance(CoCoinApplication.getAppContext()).RECORDS.size();
if (RecordManager.getInstance(CoCoinApplication.getAppContext()).SELECTED_RECORDS == null) {
    RecordManager.getInstance(CoCoinApplication.getAppContext()).SELECTED_RECORDS = new LinkedList<>();
}
RecordManager.getInstance(CoCoinApplication.getAppContext()).SELECTED_RECORDS.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    CoCoinRecord record = new CoCoinRecord();
    record.set(RecordManager.RECORDS.get(i));
    RecordManager.getInstance(CoCoinApplication.getAppContext()).SELECTED_RECORDS.add(record);
}
```

Comment: you misunderstand the for-each loop. for ( int element : arrayOrListOrCollectionOfInts )

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the foreach loop, exactly like what you want:

```
for (CoCoinRecord record1: ecordManager.RECORDS) {
    CoCoinRecord record = new CoCoinRecord();
    record.set(record1);
    RecordManager.getInstance(CoCoinApplication.getAppContext()).SELECTED_RECORDS.add(record);
}
```